# Where is the application environment set via service fabric application project available? Dockerfile or Docker container?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, docker-container

I have a containerized service fabric application project. It connects to azure container registry to download the docker image containing the web application project. I am setting the environment variable using this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-specify-environment-variables#procedure-for-specifying-environment-variables-for-services).

Does this set the environment variable on the docker file or inside the docker container?

If an environment variable with the same name exists on the docker file, then does it override the environment value that gets passed into the docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Does this set the environment variable on the docker file or inside the docker container?

No the example you mention is not exactly setting variable in dockerfile instead of it creates the environment variable during "docker run" time. So that new container will have those env present.

And in case you have a similar variable available in dockerfile than this will overwrite it.